Incorrect coordinates when plotting surface in Mayavi?
I've been trying to plot an implicit cubic surface in Mayavi, however, when I plot the surface, the coordinates of the surface is all wrong. It should be plotting from -10 to 10 for all axes, but instead I get this:

Here is the code to recreate this issue:
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab


k = 2
x, y, z = np.ogrid[-10: 10: 200j, -10: 10: 200j, -10: 10: 200j]

F = x**2 + y**2 + z**2 - x * y * z - k - 2

mlab.contour3d(F, contours=[0])
mlab.axes()
mlab.show()


I've been trying to shift and scale the coordinates but I would prefer to plot this surface accurately from the get go.

You haven't passed any information about x, y and z. So indexes are used as coordinates.
Understand that F contains nothing about -10:10. It is computed from values that goes from -10 to 10. But it does not contain the x,y,z information itself.
Just to clarify with simpler 1d example (and matplotlib, because I broke my mayavi install. But same problem),
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.ogrid[-10:10:100j]
f=np.sin(x)
plt.plot(f)
# or
x2=np.ogrid[-1:1:100j]
f2=np.sin(10*x2)
plt.plot(f2)

Would plot 2 times the exact same thing (first graph below). Because f and f2 are the exact same arrays. One was obtained from x from -10 to 10 with formula sin(x). The other from x from -1 to 1 with formula sin(10x). But matplotlib has no way to guess that. All it sees are 100 numbers.
So it plot indexes (from 0 to 99) for axes x, and those 100 values in axe y.
If you want axe x to show the orginal value, you would have to
plt.plot(x, f)
# or
plt.plot(x2,f2)

giving 2nd and 3rd graph below

So, it is the same thing for mayavi. If you pass a 3d array of f values, it only has the values. And use the indexes of that 3d array for the axes.
If you want to have your original x,y,z used, you have to pass them
mlab.contour3d(x,y,z,F, contours=[0])

Edit
I've repaired my mayavi, so I confirm the previous diagnosis. But must add another detail: x,y,z must be of the same shape as F. Which is not the case with ogrid. (Which is ironic, because I repeat quite often to people who use meshgrid or mgrid all the times that they shouldn't, and that in 99% of the cases, broadcasting would do the exact same thing, but with way less cost. But in this case, you really need the whole array. So x,y,z and F must be 3d full arrays of shape 200x200x200)
So
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab


k = 2
x, y, z = np.mgrid[-10: 10: 200j, -10: 10: 200j, -10: 10: 200j]

F = x**2 + y**2 + z**2 - x * y * z - k - 2

mlab.contour3d(x,y,z,F, contours=[0])
mlab.axes()
mlab.show()


